# how to speed up color-clustering in openCV?

Tags: opencv, cluster-analysis, data-mining, k-means, image-segmentation

for a project I want to implement a color-clustering algorithm, which replace similar colors with the average color of a cluster.

For now, I use the kmeans-algorithm to cluster the whole image . But this take's a long time. Has someone an idea how to use kmeans to cluster a color-histogram , so I can perform this algorithm?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**Downsample** the image first, then run k-means.

If you resize the image to 1/2th in both x and y, it shouldn't affect colors much, but k-means should take at most 1/4th of the time. If you resample to 1/10 of the width and height, k-means should run 100 times faster.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Color_quantization

By downsampling the image, you have less "pixels" to process during clustering. But in the end, it should produce roughly the same color scheme.

### Small summary of *k*-means:

1. It maps each object (=pixel) to the nearest cluster center (= palette entry)
2. It recomputes each palette entry to best represent the assigned points (= pixels)
3. Repeat until nothing changes anymore.

So the *real* output is not an image or image regions. It's the **palette**.

You can then **map an arbitrary image** (including the full resolution version) to this color palette by simply replacing each pixel with the closest color!

### Complexity and performance:

The complexity of k-means is `O(n*k*i)`, where `n` is the number of *pixels* you have, *k* the desired number of output colors and *i* the number of iterations needed until convergence.

`n`: by downsampling, you can easily reduce `n`, the largest factor. In many situations, you can reduce this quite significantly before you see a degradation in performance.

`k`: this is your desired number of output colors. Whether you can reduce this or not depends on your actual use case.

`i`: various factors can have an effect on convergence (including both other factors!), but the strongest probably is having good starting values. So if you have a *very fast* but low quality method to choose the palette, run it first, then use k-means to refine this palette. Maybe OpenCV already includes an appropriate heuristic for this though!

You can see, the easiest approach is to reduce `n`. You *can* reduce `n` significantly, produce an optimized palette for the thumbnail, then *rerun* k-means on the full image *refinining* this palette. As - hopefully - this will reduce the number of iterations significantly, this can sometimes perform very well.

Comment: thanks :) But how can i replace the color with the new one in the input image in this case?

Comment: That still works the same way. Map it to the closest color k-means found.

Comment: realy? The mask of one cluster has 1/2th of orginal image size. If i resize the mask up, i think the result is not exact,because it overwrites neightbour pixels on the orginal-image.

Comment: Which mask? Use the k-means *cluster centers* (=new palette). Map each pixel to the nearest color.

Answer (score 1):

My answer is not connected with histogram clusterization but recently I need to speedup clusterization procedure of my algorithm. For this I did the following:

1. Resized image to smaller one (actually it was already suggested)
2. Reduced number of colors ([image quantization](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quantization_%28image_processing%29)). I did it as suggested here: [How to reduce the number of colors in an image with OpenCV?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5906693/reduce-the-number-of-colors-in-an-image-with-opencv-python).

And this really helped me to speedup clusterization in some times. Also you can try to play around with OpenCV's [mean-shift filtering](http://docs.opencv.org/modules/imgproc/doc/filtering.html?highlight=pyrmean#pyrmeanshiftfiltering).

Comment: Actually, he wants to use k-means for color quantization. Why would you first use quantization A to then run quantization B? Note that he is not clustering images, but colors.

Comment: @Anony-Mousse What do you mean by saying `quantization A` and `B`?

Comment: see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Color_quantization -- k-means can be used for color quantization, which is probably what he is trying to do. It does not make sense to use a different color quantization before, does it?

Comment: @Anony-Mousse It will improve speed - kmeans works faster on smaller number of colors.

Comment: K-means complexity is `O(n k i)` where `n` is the number of pixels, `k` the number of clusters, and `i` is the number of iterations until convergence. Of course: if your pre-quantify the image a lot, k-means will likely need fewer iterations, but it will also degreade quality much more. Do you have any reference that says you should pre-quantify for k-means?

Comment: @Anony-Mousse sorry, I don't have it. Actually my supervisor advised me to do that.

Answer (score 0):

You need to assign a weight for each data, i.e. the number of values in the histogram bin. Then, when you compture the new value for cluster centroids, you use a weighted average instead of plain average. But the interface of OpenCV KMeans clustering does not support weighted values. YOu can use the [C clustering library](http://bonsai.hgc.jp/~mdehoon/software/cluster/software.htm) which does support it, is quite well documented (although takes examples from bioinformatics), and is easy to integrate (a single .h/.c file).