# Number of colors after color reduction

Tags: opencv

I want to know how the number of colors are calculated in the following post:

[How to reduce the number of colors in an image with OpenCV?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5906693/how-to-reduce-the-number-of-colors-in-an-image-with-opencv-in-python?answertab=active#tab-top)

Liho has mentioned 27 and 125 colors in his comment. Please explain how he got these values. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well its quite easy actually.

**27 Colors - 3 Posibilities**

- R -> 3
- G -> 3
- B -> 3

3*3*3 = 27

**125 Colors - 5 Possibilities**

- R -> 5
- G -> 5
- B -> 5

5*5*5 = 125

Comment: inline uchar reduceVal(const uchar val)
{
    if (val < 64) return 0;
    if (val < 128) return 64;
    return 255;
}

Comment: Liho Says that the image will be reduced to 27 colors using the above code . How? please explain.

Comment: @Navdeep An image in OpenCV is a Matrix, in this case there are 3 Matrices, one for each RGB channel, what he does is compare a pixel value and return a given value, so for all values between 0-63 you get 0, for values between 64-127 return 64, all other values return 255. Hence for each channel you will have 3 possible values, and 3x3x3 = 27 possible colors. Also, uchar is a byte so is between 0-255